# Faban workload generator and Darwin Streaming server (Media Streaming Benchmark)

Tags: ubuntu, streaming, media, darwin

I have followed the steps in the following documents and installed Darwin Streaming Server in an Ubuntu machine and Faban workload generator (client) in another ubuntu machine. (Actually as separate ubuntu EC2 instances in AWS cloud)

http://parsa.epfl.ch/cloudsuite/streaming.html
https://github.com/chetui/CloudSuiteTutorial/blob/master/media_streaming/README.md

When I run the Darwin Streaming server after installation, I get the runtime statistics printed in the terminal every second. But I get a warning before this, Module folder not found. Qtss Users and groups folder not found in /Library/QuickTimePlayer.

On the client side, the faban workload generator benchmark is not deployed successfully.
How to make the client communicate to the server successfully and what will be the output of this benchmarking implementation?

Please help me out with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this issue , 
"I get a warning before this, Module folder not found. Qtss Users and groups folder not found in /Library/QuickTimePlayer "

It may be due to  qtss did not create users and groups.

Solution :

Check if there qtss user grep qtss | by cat / etc / passwd,

Check if there qtss group grep qtss | by cat / etc / group

If it's not available create them.